Finding the local maxima of a function according to direction (theta, phi)
I have a CSV file with three columns:
Phi: Represents the first angle in a polar coordinate system.
Theta: Represents the second angle in a polar coordinate system.
Parameter: The value associated with a specific direction (phi, theta).
I want to identify local maxima based on the direction (theta, phi) in this CSV data by Python.
Please help, thank you so much.
The results can be calculated from the third program but it takes me a lot of time, I want to use python to find the solution.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
